# How to solve $y'+2xy=2x^3y^2$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following equation?

$$y'+2xy=2x^3y^2$$

Comment: This is a bernoulli differential equation. Divide throughout by $y^2$ and substitute $z=\frac1{y}$.

Comment: You were given a good hint in @Nicholas's comment. How far were you able to go with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y′+2xy=2x^3y^2$$
or,$$\frac{y′}{y^2}+\frac{2x}{y}=2x^3$$
or,$$-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)+2x\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)=2x^3$$
or,$$\frac{dv}{dx}-2xv=-2x^3$$ where $v=\frac{1}{y}$

This is a first order linear differential equation. Solve it by the usual way.

Comment: Downvote? An explanation should follow to justify it, isn't it downvoter?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a minus in front of the derivative term, since $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{y(x)}=-\frac{y(x)'}{y(x)^2}$? (PS I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @fibonatic Thanks for correcting me. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> $$y′+2xy=2x^3y^2 \bigg/ : 
> -y(x)^2$$

Solve Bernoulli's equasion:

Let $\nu (x)=\frac{1}{y(x)}$, wich gives $\frac{d\nu (x)}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d\nu (x)}{dx}}{y^2(x)}$

$$\frac{d\nu(x)}{dx}-2x\nu (x)=-2x^3$$

Let $\mu (x)=e^{-\int 2xdx}=e^{-x^2}$

Multiply both sides by $\mu (x):$

$$e^{-x^2}\frac{d\nu (x)}{dx}-\big( 2e^{-x^2}x \big) \nu (x)=-2e^{-2x^2}x^3$$

Substitute $-2e^{-2x^2}x=\frac{d}{dx}\big(e^{-x^2} \big)$

$$e^{-x^2}\frac{d\nu (x)}{dx}+\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(e^{-x^2} \bigg)\nu (x)=-2x^{-2x^2}x^3$$

Apply the reverse product rule $g\frac{df}{dx}+f\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(fg)$ to the left hand side:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg( e^{-x^2}\nu (x) \bigg)=-2e^{-2x^2}x^3$$

$$\int\frac{d}{dx}\bigg( e^{-x^2}\nu (x) \bigg)dx=\int-2e^{-2x^2}x^3dx$$

$$e^{-x^2}\nu (x)= -e^{-x^2}(-x^2-1)+c_1$$

Divide both sides by $\mu (x)=e^{-x^2}:$

$$\nu (x)=x^2+c_1 e^{x^2}+1$$

Solve for $y(x)$:
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{y(x)=\frac{1}{\nu (x)}=\frac{1}{x^2+c_1e^{x^2}+1}}}$$

Comment: Unusual notation

Comment: When you divide by $-y^3/2$ in the first step, the right-hand side becomes wrong. It should be $-4x^3/y$. Thus, the rest also is wrong...

Comment: @mickep The final answer is correct for sure

Comment: @mickep You should check yourself again

Comment: I insist on my comment. The right-hand side of the original differential equation is $2x^3y^2$. What do you get if you divide that by $-y^3/2$?

Comment: @mickep I'm checking...

Comment: @mickep I think that now all is good

Comment: If you in the second last formula replace $e^{-x^2}$ by $e^{x^2}$ and in the last one you remove the square root, then I agree with your answer...